# Show that if $R^n$ has an eigenvector basis for a matrix A, then there exists an eigenvector basis with respect to the transpose of A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How do I prove this?

I know that if a matrix is diagonalizable, so is its transpose. I also know that if an $n x n$ matrix has n eigenvalues, then is has an eigenbasis. How do I connect the dots?

Comment: a small suggestion, perhaps you can just say "with respect to the transpose $A^T$" in the title because at first read it could be confused with $A(A^T)$ altogether

Comment: I understand your question, it is a good one, and you are a new user so I understand that you are new to writing questions on this website, I just think that the general format in which you wrote the question MIGHT not appeal to other users, essentially where the question is mainly in the title and the body just contains something like 'I don't know where to start, plz help!!' My only suggestion would be to include anything you've tried + ideas you've had to try to solve it. Literally ANYTHING, and maybe rewrite the exact question in the body so other users can thoroughly review the question i

Comment: I just edited! My apologies

Comment: Hint. If there is an eigenvector basis what is the shape of the matrix with respect to that basis?

Answer (score 1):

Having a basis of eigenvectors is the same as a matrix being diagonalizable.

i.e. there exist an invertible matrix P such that $P^{-1}AP=D$ where $D=diag(\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2},...,\lambda_{n})$ the diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are the eigen values of $A$. The colums of this matrix $P$ are precisely the vectors in the eigen basis.

So $D=D^{t}=(P^{-1}AP)^{t}=P^{t}A^{t}(P^{t})^{-1}$ . So I assume you might know that $A$ is invertible $\iff$ $A^{t}$ is invertible. So you have your invertible matrix $(P^{t})^{-1}$ which is doing the job.

Hence $A^{t}$ has an eigen basis. In otherwords, if $P$ is the matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors of $A$. Then the eigen basis wrt which $A^{t}$ is diagonal is given by the columns of $(P^{t})^{-1}$.